# Artifactory and LDAP Configuration Issue: Manager Password Won't Persist

Tags: ldap, artifactory

I'm configuring LDAP authentication for Artifactory Pro v7.55.6. I can get the configuration to work, meaning a Test LDAP Connection is successful. However, if I save the configuration, return to the configuration screen and try again, the connection is unsuccessful until I replace the manager password again. It seems that something might by changing the password after or when I save the configuration. I don't know how to troubleshoot this.

BTW, if it matters, I'm running Artifactory in a container using Docker Compose.

I was expecting the manager password to persist after saving the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known issue starting in Artifactory 7.38.10, when testing connection the manager DN password needed to be reentered. This had no effect on actual functionality and users can still login through LDAP without having to reenter the Manager password.

This was fixed in Artifactory 7.58.0

See here for more information: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-release-information/artifactory-7.38.10?tocId=Cn67d7gNvHM02N3HR_unKg